X-Men fanfic where Gambit meets a woman at a bar where she's performing "December, 1963 (Oh, What a Night)"
I have very bare details, and there's every chance this fanfic has no remaining presence on the internet since I think I read it around 1998-2002 while I was in college. It might have been on the Fan Fic Mailing List (FFML) or on Luba Kmetyk's fanfic site "Fonts of Wisdom" (only partially available on the Internet Archive Wayback Machine) where I spent a lot of my time. The bit I remember has Gambit go to a local bar (I don't remember if he tried to go as a civilian or as an X-Man) and there's a woman singing that he takes a romantic interest in, I think talking to her after her set. I probably only read a few chapters into it (assuming it actually continued past that) and nothing really happened other than them meeting in those chapters.
What has stuck in my head is that she's singing "December, 1963" and a point is made about how she finished the line of "It ended much too soon" with a knowing wink and it really making an impression on Gambit and that moment has, as the saying goes, lived rent free in my head all these years.

If this fanfic was a multi-parter, I think I've found Part One: https://groups.google.com/g/alt.comics.fan-fiction/c/aGV-APVgG0k/m/H5Opc3SKq3QJ

And this would be the chapter with the knowing wink (actually a smirk) at that line of the song: https://groups.google.com/g/alt.comics.fan-fiction/c/oPpI6kjpOKE/m/Etlfm19ery4J - and I've just discovered it included some extracts from MY favourite song of all time as well!

I am now convinced this is "The Narrow Walk", posted to the alt.comics.fan-fiction Usenet group in the late 90s.
The bit you're remembering appears to be Chapter 1a (second part of Chapter 1 - some of the chapters were subdivided like this.) You can find it online here.
An extended quote from the story, which seems to encompass most of the points you remembered:

Immediately, everyone quieted and sat back down. She
smiled, offering her approval, then began to sing
again, this time without accompaniment:
Oh what a night!
Late December back in 63,
What a very special time for me...
As I remember, what a night.
He knew the song, Frankie Valli and the Four Seasons.
It had been a hit in the mid 70's and re-released a
few years ago. She altered the words ever so
slightly, to fit a female singer:
"Oh what a night,
You know I never even caught his name,
but I was never gonna be the same,
Sweet surrender what a night..."
She moved with the music, not just singing it, but
being it. She wasn't here to merely entertain, she
was taking an emotional journey and insisting
everyone take it with her.
"I... got a funny feeling when he walked me
In the room...
Hey, I...
As I recall it ended much too soon..."
As she sang the last line, her eyes rolled upward,
her lips twisted into a smirk. Everyone in the
audience laughed, the men a nervous laughter as if
she was hitting too close to home, the women as if to
say, "Yes, we've been there before."
Gambit had come to the bar to get drunk and wallow in
self pity, but the plans suddenly changed. He was,
instead paying full attention to this "Darkstar" ~Dat
can' be her real name. Nobody names a child Darkstar.~

You also mentioned that you thought he talked to her after her set. He does - that's in part 1c, which you can find here.

"Yeah, and I guess you were pretty impressed. So,
let's get back to the original subject. Why did you
want to talk with me?"
"B'cause I never seen anyone sing like you b'fore.
Least nobody as good as you in a bar like dat. You
wastin' your talent Chere."


That matches just about everything I remember. Thank you. Hopefully, that will ease the memory.

You're welcome - it's surprising how often a Usenet search with site:groups.google.com will unearth decades-old obscurities!
